# html in do_GET() method of a simple Python webserver

Tags: python, html, webserver, image

I am relatively new to Python but have been doing a lot of different things with it recently and I am liking it a lot. However, I ran into trouble/block with the following code.

```
import http.server
import socketserver
import glob
import random
class Server(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200, 'OK')
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<html> <head><title> Hello World </title> </head> <body>", 'UTF-8'))
        images = glob.glob('*.jpg')
        rand = random.randint(0,len(images)-1)
        imagestring = "<img src = \"" + images[rand] + "\" height = 1028 width = 786 align = \"right\"/> </body> </html>"
        self.wfile.write(bytes(imagestring, 'UTF-8'))

    def serve_forever(port):
        socketserver.TCPServer(('', port), Server).serve_forever()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Server.serve_forever(8000)
```

What I am trying to do here is grab a random image from multiple images in the directory and add it into the response to a web request.
The code works fine but when I access the server via browser, the image is not displayed. The html of the page is as intended though. The permissions on the files are 755. Also I tried to create an index.html file in the do_GET method. That didn't work either. I mean the index.html was generated fine, but the response in the browser this time did not show anything (not even the hello world in the title).

Am I missing anything very simple here? I was thinking should I overload the handle_request of the underlying SocketServer.BaseServer as the documentation says you should never override BaseHTTPServer's handle() method and should rather override the corresponding do_* method?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, you're mixing lots of `"` and `\"` in that one line:

`"<img src = \" + images[rand] + '\" height = 1028 width = 786 align = \"right\"/> </body> </html>'`

It probably should be:

```
'<img src = "' + images[rand] + '" height = 1028 width = 786 align="right"/> </body> </html>'
```

Otherwise you'll not get the image but the text `"images[rand]"`!

Comment: I'm sorry. In the actual code, it is:
imagestring = "<img src = \"" + images[rand] + "\" height = 1028 width = 786 align = \"right\"/> </body> </html>"

Comment: As an aside, composing HTML in Python like this is always nasty and I don't recommend it to non-cyborgs. For simple purposes, the Python standard library provides a simple templating system called template strings: http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings. For non-trivial projects you might want to look into using a real template engine (like Jinja2, Cheetah, etc.) Either sort of approach would be a lot more readable and remove some of the pain of dealing with escaping issues like backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that when the browser sends your server the request for the image you put into the html, you are sending them the html for another page.  You probably need to add a check at the beginning of your do_GET to make sure it isn't a request for the image (or is a request for some particular page).

Comment: Well as far images are concerned, I think the server sends the image as binary data in the same or different TCP connection (depending on the fact if you are using persistent or non-persistent HTTP). In either case, the image is wrapped around the usual HTTP headers. But I see your point, it still needs to send the image file. If you see the server responses in the terminal, you can see it responds with a 200 for image file requests.

Comment: What happens when you wget/curl the URL of the image as served from your script (i.e., the one you are navigating to in the browser)? Is the resulting file visible as an image, or does it look like HTML when you open it in a text editor?

Comment: Well using wget/curl it just sends plain html. A further investigation using tcpflow and reading into the messages passed on the loopback interface, I found that the server is not actually sending the image (as binary data). What I do see is the browser's second request for the image. Now, I could check the incoming request as a request for one of the images but the problem is how to actually send the image on the wire? As it turns out http.server does not have any encoding methods. Further reading is pointing me towards using httplib.

Answer (score 0):

I have some very similar code to your modified version (the version posted as an answer) that works for me. The only difference is that I don't send the content length, so maybe that's the cause of your problem.